# What functionality of Chrome shows a parse error as a popup?

Tags: google-chrome, nashorn

I have no clue where this is coming from: here is it, in Java I created a servlet that runs Javascript files in Nashorn and then writes the result in a response. My Javascript code returns an object like:

```
function root(){
    return {
        "hello": 1
    };
}
```

while my servlet returns the object (it was just a test):

```
 Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("root", req);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
            outputStreamWriter.write(result.toString());
            outputStreamWriter.close();
```

the response raw body is:

```
[object Object]
```

and chrome will do the following:

[image]

That red popup cross even closes it on click.

Is this done by an extension that I forgot about? Or is it some kind of integration with that syntax? I've really no idea.

Answer (score 1):

@gotch4

Result you're observing is expected. You're retuning string representation of JavaScript object (technically you're calling [`Object.protorype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) which returns `[object Object]`).
I think what you really want is to invoke `JSON.stringify` before returning response to the browser.

```
Object JSON = e.eval("JSON");
Object result = invocable.invokeMethod(JSON, "stringify", invocable.invokeFunction("root", req));

OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
        outputStreamWriter.write(result.toString());
        outputStreamWriter.close();
```

**p.s.** Code should work, but I didn't test it - writing from phone.

Comment: Hello Vik, I know that I can do that to obtain proper JSON... I was just curious to know what hidden functionality of Chrome was that